# Returning list of sorted words

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to return a list of sorted words where the letters are alphabetically sorted. For example:

```
>>> sorted_words(["bet", "abacus", "act", "celebration", "door"])

['act', 'bet', 'door']
```

My function should return a new list of sorted values, but it must keep out any words where the first letter has lower or equal unicode than the following letters. For example, "door" is appended to a new list because d' <= 'o' and 'o' <= 'o' and 'o' <= 'r'. This is what I have written so far, but I'm having no luck.

```
def sorted_words[wordlist]:
    result = []
    for word in wordlist:
        if word[0] <= word[1:]:
             result.append(word)
    print(word)
```

I know this isn't right, I just don't know how to compare the first letter of each word with the rest of the letters. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also have to use the sorted() method but I am unsure how to use that.

Comment: Try `if list(word) == sorted(word)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another loop in there, so:

```
def sorted_words(wordlist):
result = []
for word in wordlist:
    keepWord = True
    for letter in word[1:]:
        if word[0] >= letter:
            keepWord = False
            break
    if keepWord:
        result.append(word)
return result


print(sorted_words(["bet", "abacus", "act", "celebration", "door"]))
['bet', 'act', 'door']
```

Comment: Ok, so if it works, can you mark it as a correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should divide your code in two sections: the first to select the words (according to the criteria), the second to sort the selected words.

There is a discrepancy between the description of the criteria and the example.  If the criteria is "the first letter has lower or equal unicode than the following letters", then the word "abacus" should be included.  However, the explanation you provide for "door" seems to be that "the unicode values of the characters should be in (not strictly) ascending order"

("strictly ascending means `<` while non strictly means `<=` between and element and its following one).

For the first criteria, use the following code

```
WORDS = ["bet", "abacus", "act", "celebration", "door"]    
list_of_words = []
for word in WORDS:
  if all(word[0] <= c for c in word[1:]):
    list_of_words.append(word)
list_of_words.sort()
print (list_of_words)
```

For the second criteria, use

```
list2_of_words = []
for word in WORDS:
  if all(c1 <= c2 for c1,c2 in zip(word[0:-1],word[1:])):
    list2_of_words.append(word)
list2_of_words.sort()
print (list2_of_words)
```

Comment: `all` stops checking as soon as it finds a false entry, so you can make those `all` tests more efficient by feeding `all` a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. With a list comp the whole list has to be built before `all` can start work, but with a gen exp `all` will stop calling the gen exp as soon as it detects a false value. Similar remark apply to `any`.

Comment: Good suggestion, I changed the list with a generator expression.